# Error: Realm at path '/var/.../default.realm' already opened on current thread with different schema

Tags: realm

Getting this error when attempting to do `Realm.open({schema: [Schema]})` on a new build/install on an iOS device/simulator. Everything works fine on the Android application as it has never changed schemaVersions with a migration before.

My understanding of this error is that the schemaVersion of the Realm file on the device is different from the default `schemaVersion: 0` of the `Realm.open({schema: [Schema]})`. Another theory that I have is that my application is attempting to open a Realm configuration during an existing opened Realm configuration on the same file.

In order to address my first theory, I have been trying to reset the realm file with `Realm.clearTestState()` and `Realm.deleteFile({schema: [Schema]})` to no avail. For the second, I've placed concurrent `Realm.open()` instances in `setTimeout()` so that only one Realm instance is open at a time.

Is there any other method I can try to reset the Realm file so that both the Realm file on device and the configuration are both the same schemas?

Answer (score 13):

It turns out that I was not opening the Realm with the exact same schema in every instance. Meaning I was exporting multiple object schemas from my `realm.js` file and was opening them individually rather than as a whole, which I suppose is the correct method.

So basically, I was doing this...

```
Realm.open({schema: [object1, object2, object3]})
Realm.open({schema: [object4, object5]})
```

when I should've been doing this:

```
const Schema = [object1, object2, object3, object4, object5];
Realm.open({schema: Schema});
```

Hope this helps anyone else running into this issue as I had visited every other similar error report on Github and StackOverflow and had not come across this tip.

Comment: from past two days I was like how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help me...Been stuck on it for the whole day.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error message today and I'm running a react-native program. The above approach helps me to let the program goes smoothly again initially; however, at later time, after I navigating back-and-forth different pages, and once a page has several functions need to make use of the Realm for query/insert, the error message appears easily again.

Finally, I've found that, the root cause is that the instantiated Realm instance has to be closed properly. Hopes the following codes snippet help:

```
Realm.open({schema: [object1]}).then(realm => {
  realm.write(() => {
    // do whatever necessary in this transaction.
  }

  // Remember to close it at last
  realm.close();
}
```

Here an sample code regarding **Filtering** in the official site could be a reference as well: 
https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#filtering